# Encoding error while deserializing a json object from Google

Tags: python, json, encoding

As an exercise I built a little script that query Google Suggest JSON API. The code is quite simple:

```
query = 'a'
url = "http://clients1.google.co.jp/complete/search?hl=ja&q=%s&json=t" %query
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
result = json.load(response)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

If I try to `read()` the response object, this is what I've got:

```
'["a",["amazon","ana","au","apple","adobe","alc","\x83A\x83}\x83]\x83\x93","\x83A\x83\x81\x83u\x83\x8d","\x83A\x83X\x83N\x83\x8b","\x83A\x83\x8b\x83N"],["","","","","","","","","",""]]'
```

So it seams that the error is raised when python try to decode the string. This only happens with google.co.jp and the Japanese language. I tried the same code with different contry/languages and I **do not** get the same issue: when I try to deserialize the object everything works OK.

- I checked the response headers for and they always specify utf-8 as the response encoding.
- I checked the JSON string with an online parser (http://json.parser.online.fr/) and again all seams OK

Any ideas to solve this problem? What make the JSON `load()` function choke?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response header (`print response.header`) contains the following information:

```
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=Shift_JIS
```

Note the charset.

If you specify this encoding in `json.load` it will work:

```
result = json.load(response, encoding='shift_jis')
```

Comment: There's your problem: JSON is never supposed to be transferred in Shift_JIS: the only valid encodings for JSON are UTF-*. Furthermore, the actual content type of `text/javascript` is weird. Additionally, when I open that URL with Firefox, I get the same response, but in UTF-8.

Comment: @Thanatos It seems that Google make a check on the User-Agent string. If you make a request for that URL with a common browser User-Agent string (tested with IExplorer 6, Firefox 3, Safari..) you get the response encoded in UTF-8. I don't know why.

Comment: @Raben: I was thinking it might actually be the "Accept-Encoding" header - Firefox seems to explicitly request the result in either ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8, which urllib does not. Regardless, the answer given to urllib is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what the spec says, the string "\x83A\x83}\x83]\x83\x93" is not UTF-8.

At a guess, it is one of [ "cp932", "shift_jis", "shift_jis_2004", "shift_jisx0213" ]; try decoding as one of these.