# ERROR "Extra data: line 2 column 1" when using pycurl with gzip stream

Tags: python, json, pymongo, pycurl

Thanks for reading.

**Background:** 
I am trying to read a streaming API feed that returns data in `JSON` format, and then storing this data to a `pymongo collection`. The streaming API requires a `"Accept-Encoding" : "Gzip"` header.

**What's happening:**
Code fails on  `json.loads`  and outputs - `Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 4 column 1 (char 1891 - 5597)` (Refer Error Log below)

This does NOT happen while parsing every JSON object - it happens at random.

My guess is I am encountering some weird JSON object after every "x" proper JSON objects.

I did reference [how to use pycurl if requested data is sometimes gzipped, sometimes not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758243/how-to-use-pycurl-if-requested-data-is-sometimes-gzipped-sometimes-not) and [Encoding error while deserializing a json object from Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377260/encoding-error-while-deserializing-a-json-object-from-google) but so far have been unsuccessful at resolving this error.

Could someone please help me out here?

**Error Log:**
*Note:* The raw dump of the JSON object below is basically using the `repr()` method that prints the raw representation of the string without resolving CRLF/LF(s).

```
'{"id":"tag:search.twitter.com,2005:207958320747782146","objectType":"activity","actor":{"objectType":"person","id":"id:twitter.com:493653150","link":"http://www.twitter.com/Deathnews_7_24","displayName":"Death News 7/24","postedTime":"2012-02-16T01:30:12.000Z","image":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1834408513/deathnewstwittersquare_normal.jpg","summary":"Crashes, Murders, Suicides, Accidents, Crime and Naturals Death News From All Around World","links":[{"href":"http://www.facebook.com/DeathNews724","rel":"me"}],"friendsCount":56,"followersCount":14,"listedCount":1,"statusesCount":1029,"twitterTimeZone":null,"utcOffset":null,"preferredUsername":"Deathnews_7_24","languages":["tr"]},"verb":"post","postedTime":"2012-05-30T22:15:02.000Z","generator":{"displayName":"web","link":"http://twitter.com"},"provider":{"objectType":"service","displayName":"Twitter","link":"http://www.twitter.com"},"link":"http://twitter.com/Deathnews_7_24/statuses/207958320747782146","body":"Kathi Kamen Goldmark, Writers\xe2\x80\x99 Catalyst, Dies at 63 http://t.co/WBsNlNtA","object":{"objectType":"note","id":"object:search.twitter.com,2005:207958320747782146","summary":"Kathi Kamen Goldmark, Writers\xe2\x80\x99 Catalyst, Dies at 63 http://t.co/WBsNlNtA","link":"http://twitter.com/Deathnews_7_24/statuses/207958320747782146","postedTime":"2012-05-30T22:15:02.000Z"},"twitter_entities":{"urls":[{"display_url":"nytimes.com/2012/05/30/boo\xe2\x80\xa6","indices":[52,72],"expanded_url":"http://www.nytimes.com/2012/05/30/books/kathi-kamen-goldmark-writers-catalyst-dies-at-63.html","url":"http://t.co/WBsNlNtA"}],"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[]},"gnip":{"language":{"value":"en"},"matching_rules":[{"value":"url_contains: nytimes.com","tag":null}],"klout_score":11,"urls":[{"url":"http://t.co/WBsNlNtA","expanded_url":"http://www.nytimes.com/2012/05/30/books/kathi-kamen-goldmark-writers-catalyst-dies-at-63.html?_r=1"}]}}\r\n{"id":"tag:search.twitter.com,2005:207958321003638785","objectType":"activity","actor":{"objectType":"person","id":"id:twitter.com:178760897","link":"http://www.twitter.com/Mobanu","displayName":"Donald Ochs","postedTime":"2010-08-15T16:33:56.000Z","image":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1493224811/small_mobany_Logo_normal.jpg","summary":"","links":[{"href":"http://www.mobanuweightloss.com","rel":"me"}],"friendsCount":10272,"followersCount":9698,"listedCount":30,"statusesCount":725,"twitterTimeZone":"Mountain Time (US & Canada)","utcOffset":"-25200","preferredUsername":"Mobanu","languages":["en"],"location":{"objectType":"place","displayName":"Crested Butte, Colorado"}},"verb":"post","postedTime":"2012-05-30T22:15:02.000Z","generator":{"displayName":"twitterfeed","link":"http://twitterfeed.com"},"provider":{"objectType":"service","displayName":"Twitter","link":"http://www.twitter.com"},"link":"http://twitter.com/Mobanu/statuses/207958321003638785","body":"Mobanu: Can Exercise Be Bad for You?: Researchers have found evidence that some people who exercise do worse on ... http://t.co/mTsQlNQO","object":{"objectType":"note","id":"object:search.twitter.com,2005:207958321003638785","summary":"Mobanu: Can Exercise Be Bad for You?: Researchers have found evidence that some people who exercise do worse on ... http://t.co/mTsQlNQO","link":"http://twitter.com/Mobanu/statuses/207958321003638785","postedTime":"2012-05-30T22:15:02.000Z"},"twitter_entities":{"urls":[{"display_url":"nyti.ms/KUmmMa","indices":[116,136],"expanded_url":"http://nyti.ms/KUmmMa","url":"http://t.co/mTsQlNQO"}],"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[]},"gnip":{"language":{"value":"en"},"matching_rules":[{"value":"url_contains: nytimes.com","tag":null}],"klout_score":12,"urls":[{"url":"http://t.co/mTsQlNQO","expanded_url":"http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/05/30/can-exercise-be-bad-for-you/?utm_medium=twitter&utm_source=twitterfeed"}]}}\r\n'
json exception: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 4 column 1 (char 1891 - 5597)
```

**Header Output:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

Vary: Accept-Encoding

Date: Wed, 30 May 2012 22:14:48 UTC

Connection: close

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Content-Encoding: gzip
```

**get_stream.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pycurl
import json
import pymongo

STREAM_URL = "https://stream.test.com:443/accounts/publishers/twitter/streams/track/Dev.json"
AUTH = "userid:passwd"

DB_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
DB_NAME = "stream_test"

class StreamReader:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.count = 0
            self.buff = ""
            self.mongo = pymongo.Connection(DB_HOST)
            self.db = self.mongo[DB_NAME]
            self.raw_tweets = self.db["raw_tweets_gnip"]
            self.conn = pycurl.Curl()
            self.conn.setopt(pycurl.ENCODING, 'gzip')
            self.conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, STREAM_URL)
            self.conn.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, AUTH)
            self.conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, self.on_receive)
            self.conn.setopt(pycurl.HEADERFUNCTION, self.header_rcvd)
            while True:
                self.conn.perform()
        except Exception as ex:
            print "error ocurred : %s" % str(ex)

    def header_rcvd(self, header_data):
        print header_data

    def on_receive(self, data):
        temp_data = data
        self.buff += data
        if data.endswith("\r\n") and self.buff.strip():
            try:
                tweet = json.loads(self.buff, encoding = 'UTF-8')
                self.buff = ""
                if tweet:
                    try:
                        self.raw_tweets.insert(tweet)
                    except Exception as insert_ex:
                        print "Error inserting tweet: %s" % str(insert_ex)
                    self.count += 1

                if self.count % 10 == 0:
                    print "inserted "+str(self.count)+" tweets"
            except Exception as json_ex:
                print "json exception: %s" % str(json_ex)
                print repr(temp_data)



stream = StreamReader()
```

**Fixed Code:**

```
def on_receive(self, data):
        self.buff += data
        if data.endswith("\r\n") and self.buff.strip():
           # NEW: Split the buff at \r\n to get a list of JSON objects and iterate over them
            json_obj = self.buff.split("\r\n")
            for obj in json_obj:
                if len(obj.strip()) > 0:
                    try:
                        tweet = json.loads(obj, encoding = 'UTF-8')
                    except Exception as json_ex:
                        print "JSON Exception occurred: %s" % str(json_ex)
                        continue
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I owe you a drink, you solved my stress!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to paste your dumped string into [jsbeatuifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/).

You'll see that it's actually two json objects, not one, which `json.loads` can't deal with.

They are separated by `\r\n`, so it should be easy to split them.

The problem is that the `data` argument passed to `on_receive` doesn't neccessarily end with `\r\n` if it contains a newline. As this shows it also can be somewhere in the middle of the string, so only looking at the end of the data chunk won't be enough.

Comment: Thanks bud, that worked perfectly! Adding new logic under "Fixed code" for people to refer in the future.